# Cannot resolve the collation conflict?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I had this error and I don't know how to fix it

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Arabic_CI_AS" and
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

note: I already change the collation from the database option --> Collation

I change it from "Arabic_CI_AS" to "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

and I am still getting the same error !!
Any suggestion  to solve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The database collation applies only when you create NEW objects without specifying the collation.

When you change it from "Arabic_CI_AS" to "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", all the textual columns in the database are still collated `Arabic_CI_AS`.  You can check this using

```
select object_name(object_id), name, collation_name
from sys.columns
where collation_name like '%Arabic%'
```

A patch to this problem is to put `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` against the comparison, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 on X = Y COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL1
WHERE X = Y COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

etc

There is a script on [this site](http://www.db-staff.com/index.php/microsoft-sql-server/69-change-collation) that attempts to change the collation across an entire database, but

1. I have not personally tried it
2. Make sure you have a good backup of your database before trying it
3. It doesn't look like it will handle complex databases with indexed views, foreign key/default constraints etc

Comment: Also new temporary tables use tempdb's collation, not the current database's collation.

Comment: when i run 
select object_name(object_id), name, collation_name
from sys.columns
where collation_name like '%Arabic%'

it return no data at all!!

but when i change it to 
select object_name(object_id), name, collation_name
from sys.columns
where collation_name like '%SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS%'

it is returning all data !

so where is the problem ??

and i used this one also 

alter database dbname collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

but no progress !!!

Comment: @HAJJAJ, in that case, try this `select databasepropertyex('master', 'collation')` It could be the server(and tempdb) is Arabic, and the database is latin.

Comment: ahm ahm... may i know how to change this one ?!!

Comment: @HAJJAJ It is a mess. Usually, I just create a new instance using the same collation as the database, and attach to it there.  To make specific queries work, use `collate database_default` as shown above

Comment: well ,i am really very grateful for your help , and forgave me for wasting your time

thank you very much.

that is the answer i was looking for it since three months .